# Is there a case when an integer loses its precision when casted to double?

Tags: c, casting

Suppose I have

```
int i=25;
double j=(double)i;
```

Is there a chance that `j` will have values `24.9999999..upto_allowed` or `25.00000000..._upto_allowed_minus_one_and_then_1`. I remember reading such stuff somehere but not able to recall properly.

**In other words:**

Is there a case when an integer loses its precision when casted to double?

Comment: Please explain your question more understandable.

Comment: It depends. Most computers use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-754) floating point numbers, where integers between -2⁵³ and 2⁵³ are represented exactly. On ILP32 and LP64 architectures (which most 32-bit and 64-bit architectures are), `int` is 32 bit, this means the `double` type can represent all `int` values exactly.

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham : Sorry it is a bit messy. See the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For small numbers like `25`, you are good. For very large (absolute) values of `int`s on architecture where `int` is 64 bit (having a value not representable in 53 bits) or more, you will loose the precision.

[Double precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has 53 bits of precision of which Most significant bit is (implicitly) usually `1`.

On Platforms where floating point representation is not IEEE-754, answer may be a little different. For more details you can refer chapter [5.2.4.2.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2) of C99/C11 specs

Answer (score 3):

An IEEE-754 `double` has a significand precision of 53-bits. This means it can store all signed integers within the range 2^53 and -2^53.

[image: IEEE 754 Floating Point]

Because `int` typically has 32 bits on most compilers/architectures, `double` will usually be able to handle `int`.

Comment: A little better than before. You should cover both cases when `int` is 16-32 (or 53) bits and when it is larger. I would be happy to retract my vote then.

Comment: I think you also need to provide a link to the source of that diagram.

Comment: It still says **can store all `int`s** which is wrong

Comment: "signed integers which are less than or equal to 53-bits wide."  is true, yet a `double` can also represent "signed integers which are less than or equal to 54-bits wide.".  A 754 `double` has 53 bits of precision (52 explicitly stored) _and_ a sign bit.  This allows exact coding of all `int54_t` and `uint53_t`, should such types exist.

Comment: @chux There's 53 bits of information to work with, so we can store (with exact precision) only 53-bits of information. And since 0 is duplicated due to the signed bit, we can only store log2(2^53 - 1) bits in this particular case.

Comment: A 754 `double` can represent exactly every integer from  `(2^53) ...  -(2^53)`.  Simply provide a sample number in that range that fails if not convinced.

Comment: @chux Your range contains log2(2^53 - -(2^53)) ~= 54-bits of information. We only have 52+1 bits of information to work with _at most_.

Comment: We do _not_ "only have 52+1 bits" to work with - we have more.    Review [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).  `double` has 53 bits of precision and a sign bit.  That allows one to save any `int54_t` which has a sign bit and 53 value bits. Again, simple come up with an integer value that fails my assertion.

Comment: @chux Ah, I was not aware that there was an implicit 1 added onto the fractional component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109725/discussion-between-chux-and-mateen-ulhaq).

Answer (score 1):

[@Mohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734339/2410359) answer is good for practicle coding.

By the C spec, `DBL_DIG` or `FLT_RADIX/DBL_MANT_DIG` and `INT_MAX/INT_MIN` are  important values.

`DBL_DIG` in the max decimal digits a number can have that when converted to `double` and back will certainly have the same value.  It is *at least* 10.  So a whole number like 9,999,999,999 can certainly convert to a `double` and back without losing precision.   Possible larger values can successfully round-trip too.

The real round-trip problem begin with integer values exceeding `+/-power(FLT_RADIX, DBL_MANT_DIG)`.  `FLT_RADIX` is the floating point base (and is overwhelmingly `2`) and `DBL_MANT_DIG` is the "number of base-`FLT_RADIX` digits in the floating-point significand" such as `53` with IEEE-754 binary64.

Of course an `int` has the range `[INT_MIN ... INT_MAX]`.  The range must be *at least* [-32767...+32,767].

When, mathematically, `power(FLT_RADIX, DBL_MANT_DIG) >= INT_MAX`, there is no conversion problems.  This applies to all conforming C compilers.